# java.io.IOException: Unexpected response code for CONNECT: 405

Tags: java, web-services

Sometimes when I am inside my app, I get the following error :

**java.io.IOException: Unexpected response code for CONNECT: 405**

It doesn't effect my app as far as I know. But can anyone tell why it keep coming sometimes and what is it..?

Comment: HTTP 405 is "Method not allowed". So the server (or more likely proxy) did not like your CONNECT request.

Comment: Can you elaborate more..? og provide a link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remote server must have a handler for the `HTTP CONNECT` method, otherwise you'd get a `405 Method not allowed`.